# use of 'read' before 'watch' - RiverPod

Tags: dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I have this setup:

```
final totalStatesOfAssignmentsByRoom = StreamProvider.family<List<int>?, Room>(
  (ref, room) async* {
    List<int> statusCount = [];

    // some logic
    yield statusCount;
  },
);
```

At some point when I need to get the List for a room (in a function):

```
var list = ref
  .read(totalStatesOfAssignmentsByRoom(
    Room(
      roomId: roomId,
      notificationType: notificationType,
    ),
  ))
  .value;
```

This returns null.

If I change 'read' to 'watch' I get the List.

AFAIK, it appears that the StreamProvider must be 'watched' before it is 'read'.

As per recommended guidelines we are to 'read' and not 'watch' unless we are in the build method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using watch when you want the value.  You should use read only when you want to get at the notifier, like in a callback or a stateful-widget lifecycle method.

Comment: Is that not reversed? Watch is used in stateful widgets so that they are rebuilt when they are notified, while read is used to get the value...

Comment: I don't think we're exactly disagreeing, but you should be using watch in the build method, and read pretty much everywhere else.